# Load 2 php variables in 1 Json object for usage in graph

Tags: javascript, php, json

I would like to load 2 types of data for my graph. I have got 2 php variables:

$rows and $rows1

I currently have got the following jsone encode whitch works fine:

```
echo json_encode(array("className" => ".main.l1","data" => $rows));
```

But now I would like to add the 2nd set of data. It should have the class name .main.l2 in order to work.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to work: (the className gets overwritten)

```
echo json_encode(array("className" => ".main.l1","data" => $rows,"className" => ".main.l2","data" => $rows1));
```

Does anyone know how I can prevent .main.l2 overwrinting .main.l2?

The output has to look something like this:

```
{"className":".main.l1","data":[{"x":"2013-11-17","y":4831642},{"x":"2013-11-18","y":6039726},{"x":"2013-11-19","y":6161756},{"x":"2013-11-20","y":5982313},{"x":"2013-11-21","y":5916902},{"x":"2013-11-22","y":5300133},{"x":"2013-11-23","y":4801745}]},{"className":".main.l2","data":[{"x":"2013-11-17","y":4831642},{"x":"2013-11-18","y":6039726},{"x":"2013-11-19","y":6161756},{"x":"2013-11-20","y":5982313},{"x":"2013-11-21","y":5916902},{"x":"2013-11-22","y":5300133},{"x":"2013-11-23","y":4801745}]}
```

Can anyone help me on this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a multi-dimensional array. Like this:

```
$array = array(
    array("className" => ".main.l1","data" => $rows),
    array("className" => ".main.l2","data" => $rows1)
);
echo json_encode($array);
```